# Segfault on very simple source

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, freetype

I'm trying to write a simple script using the FreeType library. The segfault is occurring during execution of the FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes method, though I'm using it correctly. Any help would be great. Here's the full code:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

main() {

    FT_Library library;
    FT_Face face;
    FT_GlyphSlot slot;
    FT_UInt glyph_index = 30;
    char* font_file = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf";

    // Render font
    FT_New_Face(library, font_file, 0, &face);

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 16); /* THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE SEGFAULT */

    slot = face->glyph;
    FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT);
    FT_Render_Glyph(face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: I thought I saw this question a few minutes ago ?

Comment: So what does the return value of `FT_New_Face` have to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not initialize your `Library` variable : see [`FT_LIBRARY` documentation](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Library). You should use [`FT_Init_FreeType`](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Init_FreeType) :

> FT_Init_FreeType
>
> Defined in FT_FREETYPE_H (freetype/freetype.h).
>
> FT_EXPORT( FT_Error )   FT_Init_FreeType( FT_Library  *alibrary );
>
> Initialize a new FreeType library object. The set of modules that are
>   registered by this function is determined at build time.
>
> output alibrary    A handle to a new library object.
>
> return FreeType error code. 0 means success.

You could first get used to this library following this [tutorial](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html). Take care to check the return values too ...

Comment: Yep, you're right. I've been through the tutorial and this was my first attempt at writing something from scratch. Looks like I just forgot about initialization. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized your library.

```
FT_Library library;
error = FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
if (error) { /* report error and exit */ }
```

You also have to check return values of functions like shown above. For instance, `FT_New_Face` returns an error (as it probably does in your case), you must not access `face` because it is left in an undefined state.